# Como conectar mi aplicacion a una base de datos externa?

Tags: android-studio, webservice

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación que debe de recuperar información desde una base de datos externa, tengo que recuperar texto he imágenes, no se que es mas recomendable usar, usar Firebase o Google Cloud, o desarrollar el web Service, si desarrollo el web service como puedo recuperar también imágenes que estén en algún servidor, todo lo quiero mostrar en card view y toda la información que se muestre lo quiero recuperar desde una base de datos externa.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Enrique,  tu pregunta es demasiado amplia y basada en opiniones, primeramente te sugiero revisar https://expocodetech.com/como-crear-una-lista-con-recyclerview/ y después http://www.hermosaprogramacion.com/2015/12/consumir-un-servicio-web-rest-desde-android/ Te sugiero revises [answer]  para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida en la comunidad, saludos!

Comment: @Jorgesys Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, me sirvió bastante ya logre hacer la conexión.